# Project Euler: Sum varying by a significant margin

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to solve problem 22 on Project Euler...which is as follows:

```
**Using names.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list to obtain a name score.

For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN, which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.

What is the total of all the name scores in the file?**
```

Here's the code that I wrote to solve this problem:

```
f = open("F:\gnames.txt", "r")
strr = f.read()
w = strr.replace('"', "")
li = w.split(',')
dic = {}
sum = 0
for ee in li:
    for e in ee:
        if (e == "A"):
            sum+=1
        elif (e == "B"):
            sum+=2
        elif (e == "C"):
            sum+=3
        elif (e == "D"):
            sum+=4    
        elif (e == "E"):
            sum+=5
        elif (e == "F"):
            sum+=6
        elif (e == "G"):
            sum+=7
        elif (e == "H"):
            sum+=8
        elif (e == "I"):
            sum+=9
        elif (e == "J"):
            sum+=10
        elif (e == "K"):
            sum+=11
        elif (e == "L"):
            sum+=12
        elif (e == "M"):
            sum+=13
        elif (e == "N"):
            sum+=14
        elif (e == "O"):
            sum+=15
        elif (e == "P"):
            sum+=16
        elif (e == "Q"):
            sum+=17
        elif (e == "R"):
            sum+=18
        elif (e == "S"):
            sum+=19
        elif (e == "T"):
            sum+=20
        elif (e == "U"):
            sum+=21
        elif (e == "V"):
            sum+=22
        elif (e == "W"):
            sum+=23
        elif (e == "X"):
            sum+=24
        elif (e == "Y"):
            sum+=25
        else:
            sum+=26
    dic[ee] = sum
    sum = 0
x = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])
main_sum = 0
index = 0
for c in x:
    t = c[1]*index
    main_sum = main_sum + t
    index+=1
print main_sum
```

The actual answer is 871198282. However, my code gives the answer as 995996966, which is off by 124798684 compared to the actual answer. What seems to be the problem with my code?

Comment: I'm guessing the file still has other characters than letters in it, despite your `replace` and `strip` calls. Try changing the end of your `if`/`elif` chain to `elif e == "Z": sum += 26; else: print("Found unknown character: {!r}".format(e))` and see if anything gets reported.

Comment: Nope. Nothing gets reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is in the line `x = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])`. This sorts the dictionary items by the scores, not alphabetically by the names. Change `t[1]` to `t[0]` in the lambda and I suspect you'll get a better result.

Another possible issue (it's a little ambiguous) is your indexing when you go to add up the scores. You're starting `index` at zero, but the instructions suggest that the 938th name should be multiplied by 938, not by its zero-based index, which would be 937. You probably need to start with `index = 1`.

Comment: Yes..it gives me the correct answer now ! Thanks a ton.